# How to migrate all packages to elementary OS

Tags: package-management

I wish to switch to elementary OS from Ubuntu. Thing is, I've installed lots of software on Ubuntu. And I'm not patient enough to install all of them again once I install elementary OS. Is there any way that I can compress all the packages in a single file and just decompress it in elementary OS and install packages just like that?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool "apt-clone" for this.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man8/apt-clone.8.html

But i would recommend to start fresh and install only those packages you currently use..